# GAM: cox regression doesn't fit my synthetic data

Tags: cox-model, mgcv

I want to understand how Cox regression work using `gam` and `mgcv`, so I want to make my own data and try to see if I can fit a model. The problem is that the regression model can't seem to pick up all the variance that I introduce in the data. Do you guys know why this is?

```
library(mgcv)    
library(data.table)
set.seed(1234)
N=10000
time_n=40
data <- data.table(
  villain = as.factor(rep(c("1", "2"), each=N/2)),
  grade = as.factor(sample(c("A", "B", "C"), N, replace=T)),
  time = pmax(pmin(as.integer(rnorm(N, time_n-10, 10)), time_n), 4)
)
data[, hazard_ratio := 1]
data[villain=="2", hazard_ratio := hazard_ratio * 1.5]
data[grade=="C", hazard_ratio := hazard_ratio * 2]
data[grade=="B", hazard_ratio := hazard_ratio * 4]
data[, S_0 := exp(-time/time_n)] # or: data[, S_0 := 1-(time/(time_n*2))]
data[, S := S_0^hazard_ratio]
data[, status := rbinom(N, 1, 1-S)]

gam.model <- gam(time ~ villain + grade, 
                 data=data, family="cox.ph", weights=status)

data$pred <- predict(gam.model, newdata=data, type="response")
```

Looking at https://rdrr.io/cran/mgcv/man/coxph.html I see that: `Prediction from the fitted model object (using the predict method) with type="response" will predict on the survivor function scale`. So I'm supposed to be able to compare `S` in my data to `pred`, but `pred` is way off.
Also, looking at the coefficients of my model, they are way off:

[image: summary(gam.model)]

**EDIT**: is the problem that I'm defining the survival functions wrongly, perhaps? I got it from here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_ratio under `The hazard ratio and survival`. Or is it the way I'm using the `binomial` family?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are simulating random times from a coursened truncated normal distribution then plugging those times into a survival probability used to change the status but not the event times.  Also the programming makes things unclear.  Start with a simple exponential distribution and make sure that random numbers are generated at the right spots.  Specify the linear predictor in one go.  Here is an example that also makes the code clear, taken from [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rms/versions/6.2-0/topics/cph)

```
require(survival)
n <- 1000
set.seed(731)
age <- 50 + 12*rnorm(n)
sex <- factor(sample(c('Male','Female'), n, 
              rep=TRUE, prob=c(.6, .4)))
cens <- 15*runif(n)
# Hazard ratio for female:male is exp(0.8)
h    <- .02*exp(.04*(age-50)+.8*(sex=='Female'))
dt   <- -log(runif(n))/h   # generates exponential dist. event times
e    <- ifelse(dt <= cens,1,0)
dt   <- pmin(dt, cens)
S    <- Surv(dt,e)
coxph(S ~ age + sex)
```

Comment: Thank you professor! I get it! Is there any way of getting to the survival function from your specified hazard rate `h` above? Such that I can verify that my predictions are in accordance to a pre-specified survival function?

Comment: For the simple exponential distribution $S(t) = \exp(h \times t)$.  $h$ is the hazard rate computed above.

Comment: Awesome, thanks :)